# How can I extract URL of image from a list of Amazon web pages?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd

listt=[list of web pages]

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

imgss = []
for i in range(len(listt)):
    print(i)
    html = urlopen(listt[i])
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('PATTERN.jpg')})
    for image in images:
        imgss.append(image['src'])
```

There are about 1100 URLs of **Amazon** web pages in the listt. It works for some initial web pages but after that, it throws error : **HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable** .

Comment: It throws error ? Can you add what kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to acces element attributes

```
imgss.append(image.attrs['src'])
```